# ReactJS: Show status with red / green background depending on axios post result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a form, where I need to show the status below the form. When I submit the form, depending on axios post success and failure I show the status. As of today I am able to show the error status as below [image]

What I want when the submit is successful, I want to show status as below.

[image]

I have below code.

```
//State
const [stats, setStatus] = useState(null);

//axios post
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/exec/addcontroller', 
                {user, name, ipaddr, port, sshuser, sshpass, sshport, license},
                {headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': token,
                }}
            ).then( function (res) {
                if(res.status === 200) {
                    //success
                } else {
                    setStatus("Error");
                }
            });
        }catch(err) {
            setStatus(err.response.data.message);
        }

//form code goes here

//status div
{status && <div id="error">{status}</div>}
```

and css looks as below

```css
#error {
  color: #FF0040;
  border: 1px solid #F7819F;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F8E0E6;
}
```

So what I need in success case, I want to show status in dark green letter and background as light green. How to do that react way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add some more information to your state (or use multiple state variables) to indicate not only the message but the error status as well.

Try something like this using an object with `type` and `message` properties

```js
setStatus(null);
try {
  const data = { user, name, ipaddr, port, sshuser, sshpass, sshport, license };
  const res = await axios.post('/exec/addcontroller', data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
    },
  });
  setStatus({
    type: 'success',
    message: `Controller ${name} added successfully`,
  });
} catch (err) {
  setStatus({
    type: 'error',
    message: err.response?.data.message ?? 'An error occurred',
  });
}
```

and render it like this

```jsx
{status && <div className={`alert ${status.type}`}>{status.message}</div>}
```

You could use an `id` instead of `className` but I feel CSS classes make more sense here.

```css
.alert {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.alert.error {
  color: #ff0040;
  background-color: #f8e0e6;
  border-color: #f7819f;
}

.alert.success {
  color: darkgreen;
  border-color: darkgreen;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

---

Note that I removed the `Content-Type` header from the request. It was completely redundant in this case.